# Kernel and dimension of the kernel from a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear transformation $T: M_{22} \rightarrow R^2$ with mapping: $T ([\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d \\\end{matrix}]) = (3a - 4b + c, 2a + b - d)$. Find ker[T] and dimension of this ker[T] and explain!

I am quite used to linear transformation from $M_{22}$ to $P_1$ or an $R$ to another $R$, so I'm not quite sure how to do this. Help's appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finding the kernel is equivalent to finding the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3& -4 &1 & 0\\
2& 1 &0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which you can compute easily (why?).

Comment: I'm sorry, but just like that? What's the difference between finding from M22 to P1, R3 to R4, with M22 to R2?